# PHP header() failing in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: php, google-chrome, header

The following code works in Safari but not Firefox or Chrome

```
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    ob_end_flush();
    exit;
```

The webpage at XXXX might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Error code: ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

$file variable links to a file outside of the public_html directory.

I can't seem to find a fix, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've had issue with filesize() on chrome and firefox in the past. This was my fix.

```
   <?php
    Function real_filesize($file) {

      $fmod = filesize($file);
      if ($fmod < 0) $fmod += 2.0 * (PHP_INT_MAX + 1);
      $i = 0;
      $myfile = fopen($file, "r");
      while (strlen(fread($myfile, 1)) === 1) {
        fseek($myfile, PHP_INT_MAX, SEEK_CUR);
        $i++;
      }
      fclose($myfile);
      if ($i % 2 == 1) $i--;

      return ((float)($i) * (PHP_INT_MAX + 1)) + $fmod;

    }


    $filename = "somefile.ext";
    $filepath = "some/dir/path/to/file/".$filename;
    $filesize = real_filesize($filepath);

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download'); 
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($filename).";");
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($filepath);
    exit();
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just removed the line `ob_clean()` worked for me.